# Tensorflow ObjectDetection generate_script.py attribute error

Tags: python, tensorflow, proto

Sorry, I am fairly new to tensorflow and I am trying some projects alongside a tutorial in object detection but I encountered an error from the tutorial's tfrecord generation with the generate_script.py file.

The code that is beeing used for the tf generation is this:

```
    SCRIPTS_PATH = 'Tensorflow/scripts'
    ANNOTATION_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/annotations'
    IMAGE_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/images'

    !python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l{ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o{ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
    !python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l{ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o{ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}
```

And both the !python commands output this error:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\protos\string_int_label_map_pb2.py", line 20, in <module>
    _LVISFREQUENCY = DESCRIPTOR.enum_types_by_name['LVISFrequency']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enum_types_by_name'

>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\protos\string_int_label_map_pb2.py", line 20, in <module>
    _LVISFREQUENCY = DESCRIPTOR.enum_types_by_name['LVISFrequency']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enum_types_by_name'
```

from what I know, the generate_tfrecord.py is an official script which is why a am confused.

upon threading the error this is what the lines that generates the error from 'strings_int_label_map_pb2.py' file:

```
    from google.protobuf import descriptor_pool as _descriptor_pool
    DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor_pool.Default().AddSerializedFile(b'\n2object_detection/protos/string_int_label_map.proto\x12\x17object_detection.protos\"\xc1\x02\n\x15StringIntLabelMapItem\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\n\n\x02id\x18\x02 \x01(\x05\x12\x14\n\x0c\x64isplay_name\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12M\n\tkeypoints\x18\x04 \x03(\x0b\x32:.object_detection.protos.StringIntLabelMapItem.KeypointMap\x12\x14\n\x0c\x61ncestor_ids\x18\x05 \x03(\x05\x12\x16\n\x0e\x64\x65scendant_ids\x18\x06 \x03(\x05\x12\x39\n\tfrequency\x18\x07 \x01(\x0e\x32&.object_detection.protos.LVISFrequency\x12\x16\n\x0einstance_count\x18\x08 \x01(\x05\x1a(\n\x0bKeypointMap\x12\n\n\x02id\x18\x01 \x01(\x05\x12\r\n\x05label\x18\x02 \x01(\t\"Q\n\x11StringIntLabelMap\x12<\n\x04item\x18\x01 \x03(\x0b\x32..object_detection.protos.StringIntLabelMapItem*D\n\rLVISFrequency\x12\x0f\n\x0bUNSPECIFIED\x10\x00\x12\x0c\n\x08\x46REQUENT\x10\x01\x12\n\n\x06\x43OMMON\x10\x02\x12\x08\n\x04RARE\x10\x03')
```